# How to run multiple Test cases on different browsers in TestNG with Java

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, testng

I'm new at TestNG.

So, I want to know more details about how to run multiple test-cases on different browsers. Which Framework model should I use in my project? So that each & every part of my code is clear & understandable?

Right now I have about 30 Test Cases that I have to run on different browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using TestNG.xml we can easily run number of test cases on multiple browser. Is it right?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <suite name="Suite" parallel="false">
      <test name="Test1">
      <parameter name="browserType" value="firefox"/>
        <classes>
          <class name="crossBrowserTesting.Magento_RAR_Framework"/>
        </classes>
      </test> <!-- Test -->
      <test name="Test2">
        <parameter name="browserType" value="chrome"/>
        <classes>
          <class name="crossBrowserTesting.Magento_RAR_Framework"/>
        </classes>
      </test> <!-- Test -->
      <test name="Test3">
        <parameter name="browserType" value="ie"/>
        <classes>
          <class name="crossBrowserTesting.Magento_RAR_Framework"/>
        </classes>
      </test> <!-- Test -->
    </suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve parallel execution of test cases on different browsers, you can go for [Selenium Grid](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2).

It lets you run your tests on different machines having different browsers using a hub and node concept.
If you don't have any other machine available, you can use your local system and register it as a hub and a node as well.

Comment: Is it possible to run same test cases on single machine with  multiple browser?
I think by using TestNG.xml file we can easily run it. Is it correct?